# How to get central position on map and and radius of visibility?

Tags: ios, ios5

How to get central position on map and and radius of visibility ?
(radius in km or m)
In app I have map ( zoom in/zoom out) and when user move on map to see another town I need to send another request  where I need to find all points inside circle with center in map center and radius ( radius on screen is height_screen

Comment: What have you tried? Did you consult the docs? They are pretty clear about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should take a look at [MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).

`visibleMapRect` The area currently displayed by the map view.

`centerCoordinate` The map coordinate at the center of the map view.

both will be changed when you zoom in/out or move the map.